# EditText width not increasing at runtime

Tags: android, android-edittext, width

This is my view

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">



        <EditText
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:id="@+id/defaultfragmentquicktask"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Quick Task"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/voicerecognition"
            android:id="@+id/catalogactivityvoicerecognition"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/defaultfragmentcamera"
            android:src="@mipmap/camera"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/defaultfragmentdrawingbrush"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/drawingbrush"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/defaultfragmentsavebutton"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@mipmap/defaulfragmentsave"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

When edittext gets focus i am setting camera,voice recognition and drawingbrush image's visibilty to gone and save image button's visibilty to visible.I wanted to move save button to the extreme right but it is not moving and i know it can be done using RelativeLayout but i dont want to do that,so i am incresing edittext width when it gets focus.
i used the following to increase its width but nothing works
edittext.getLayoutParams().width=32;
edittext.setWidth(32); and edittext.setEms(50);
Please help me to move savebutton to extreme right using LinearLayout, i already tried gravity="right",it doesnt work or let me know how to increase edittext width at runtime?

```
 View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                voiceRecognitionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                camerButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                drawingbrush.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                quickTaskEditText.setWidth(330);
            } else {
                voiceRecognitionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                camerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                drawingbrush.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                save.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                quickTaskEditText.setWidth(220);
            }
        }
    };
```

inOnCreateView of my fragment

```
quickTaskEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.defaultfragmentquicktask);
quickTaskEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
```

Comment: Show a code where you are updating width of your EditText. Currently its hardcoded to 220dp

Comment: I have added the code,please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width by using the following code:

`final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(your width, your height); // Width , height  edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams); return edittext;`

If you want your edit text to move to extreme right you can add a rule 
```
alignParentRight = true;

```

Hope this helps

Comment: That alignParentRight rule will work with RelativeLayout only.

Comment: I am creating the edittext in layout file itself and not at runtime.I just want to change the width on its focus and if i use final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(your width, your height); // Width , height  edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams); my app crashes

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply params back to your View.

```
LayoutParams param = yourView.getLayoutParams(); // Get existing params
param.width = 330;
yourView.setLayoutParams(param); // Apply updated params
```

Comment: One more thing which you have to notice is, you are setting width in dp from your xml like 220dp but from java code you are setting values in pixels

Comment: I did this float density = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                float px = 330 * density;
                quickTaskEditText.setWidth(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(px))); & whenever i click on my edittext,the app crashes

Comment: Even did this,DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                float logicalDensity = metrics.density;
                int px = (int) Math.ceil(330 * logicalDensity);
                quickTaskEditText.setWidth(px); but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

In if (hasFocus) i am setting

```
voiceRecognitionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                camerButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

instaed of GONE so that save image button appears at the extreme right